# Port finding race condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, port, race-condition

I have a master.js and a slave.js

Whenever the master.js needs more slaves to handle data, it will .fork them.

In slave.js (truncated)

```
portscanner.findAPortNotInUse(config.wss.start_port, config.wss.end_port)
.then((port) => {
    httpsServer.listen(port);
    process.send('Connected and listening on : ' + port);
})
```

Start Port is 11001 and End Port is 11100.

Now sometimes slave4 and slave5 both think that 11004 is free, both bind to that port and throw EADDRINUSE.

master.js

```
function CreateSlave(mode, amount) {
    return new Promise((res) => {

        var c = connected_slaves;
        for (var i = 0; i < amount; i++) {

            var id = uuid.v4().split("-")[0];

            slaves[c] = fork('/opt/nodeapps/ass/slave/server.js',
            [serverKeyForSession, mode]);
            slaves[c].id = id;
            slaves[c].mode = mode;

            AttachHandlerToSlave(c).then((res) => {
                if (res) return;
            });
            c++;
        }
    });
}

function AttachHandlerToSlave(c) {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        slaves[c].on('message', (msg) => {
            console.log('\x1b[33m['+ slaves[c].id +'] | \x1b[0m'+msg);
        });
        res(true);
    });
}
```

How can I prevent such behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your **master process** to transmit the port number to the **slaves**.

When forking you automatically open a channel of communication between the **master** and the **slave**. Use it.

[Here](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a) is a good tutorial about child processes.

---

**I quote :**

---

**parent.js**

```
const { fork } = require('child_process');

const forked = fork('child.js');

forked.on('message', (msg) => {
  console.log('Message from child', msg);
});

forked.send({ hello: 'world' });
```

---

**slave.js**

```
process.on('message', (msg) => {
  console.log('Message from parent:', msg);
});

let counter = 0;

setInterval(() => {
  process.send({ counter: counter++ });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Oh I can use .send too? nice. I was just using process.send on the slave to get status updates

Comment: @DatNoHand I've added the full example of communication, you can find in the provided link.

Comment: But how should the parent know which ports are open?

Comment: When you are the master you can keep data about the number of slaves you have and the available ports you have. When you start a new slave, give to it an available port that you remove from the array of port you are keeping on.